# How to remove .php File extension for a single file? (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've searched the web, but I couldn't find how to hide the .php extension for a single file

(/foo.php to /foo)

How could I do this to this particular file, without touching any of the other ones, using .htaccess

*(the answer is probably simple, but I'm either stupid or didn't look hard enough)*

Comment: You are looking for URL rewriting (see mod_rewrite)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that you want your users to enter `/foo` in the browser and really get to `/foo.php` behind the scenes (eg: to have pretty URLs), you need an internal redirect. Add the following to `.htaccess` file in the site's top public folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^foo$    /foo.php     [END,QSA,NC]
```

**How it works**

1. Your server receives a request for content at path `/foo`
2. Server finds the rule above, and forwards the request and internally changes the path to `/foo.php`
3. `END` flag: the request is sent to `/foo.php` immediately. Use `L` instead in old versions of Apache ([see docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end))
4. `QSA` flag: request parameters are also forwarded (eg: /foo?**item=7**)
5. `NC` flag: case insensitive match. `/FOO` will also be forwarded to `/foo.php`

Comment: I want /foo to be entered in the browser, but it's really just foo.php. I should rephrase *remove* to *hide*

Comment: I gave you instructions to do that.

Comment: I end up getting an 500 internal error `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.` The error log says `/.htaccess: RewriteRule: unknown flag 'END'`

Comment: I just removed the `END` flag and everything works fine now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You probably have an old Apache version. Use `L` tag instead.

Comment: Ok, the `L` tag works too. I'm using dreamhost (which i think uses the latest phpMyAdmin) *apparently not I guess*

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` doesn't have anything to do with this. Glad you got it working though; I've edited that part of my answer.

Comment: QSA flag is not really required here as the destination does not contain a querystring.

Comment: A similar argument can be made about every flag I included.  How do we know that `foo.php` doesn't use any query params? Because the OP doesn't specify one way or the other, and because missing params would be difficult to debug for someone who doesn't know about the `QSA` flag, I think it's best to include it.  I don't see what harm it does to have it and not need it, but it would be a real pain to not know about it and wonder why params aren't working

Comment: Thnx, I was planning on using query params, glad I know now :)